# How? (for blender 2.8) to set hotkeys for specific screen space (workflow editors)?

Tags: customization

I used to have a pie menu hotkey that let me go to node editor, or UV editor or video editor.

Within preferences, calling each editor was `Screen.set_layout`, then there was another box within that hotkey that allowed you to put the name of the editor you wanted.

In Blender 2.8 I don't know what words/code to put in there.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.80 screen layouts have been replaced with [workspaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/workspaces.html). This refers to the entire layout of blenders window.

Using python we can change the [active workspace](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window.workspace) with

```
nws = bpy.data.workspaces['Animation']
bpy.context.window.workspace = nws
```

I don't see an operator that allows us to change the workspace in 2.80, at least not without creating a new workspace. That would require writing an addon to add that functionality.

We *can* change the current editor (the one the cursor is over), to do that we use

```
bpy.ops.screen.space_type_set_or_cycle(space_type='VIEW_3D')
```

To use that in your custom pie menu

```
row.operator("screen.space_type_set_or_cycle").space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

When using that in the kemap editor, you enter `screen.space_type_set_or_cycle` and then choose the editor type in the menu.

[image: setting an editor hotkey]

You will find within the window group of hotkeys, where you want to add your hotkeys for this, combining <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> with <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> is already setup to switch editors. The NLA, Info and Preferences being the editors with no hotkey setup.