# Is It Possible to Have Hotkeys which Automatically Change when Choosing Different Workspaces?

Tags: interface, shortcut, workspaces

(In Blender 2.82a)

I want the spacebar to play and stop animations, but only when I'm in the Animation workspace. I want the spacebar to select the different sculpting brushes, also, but only when I'm in the Sculpting workspace. The spacebar has been given a lot of work to do in Blender, but in my view, the solution to it having so many expected functions was not to require modifier keys to be used so that all of those expected functions could continue to be preserved (leading to a user experience which I find clumsy when involving such a physically large key, and therefore error prone). Rather, it was to incorporate something like what I am proposing: Workspace specific shortcuts. But apparently, that wasn't done.

So how do *I* do it? Probably with scripting. But I know nothing about that.

Comment: See the `__init__.py` of workspace Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152673/new-default-file-template   Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144655/how-for-blender-2-8-to-set-hotkeys-for-specific-screen-space-workflow-editor